# How to check if several dates lie within a interval using data.table and lubridate?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I have a data.table with several columns with dates,
and two columns defining an interval.
I want to check if any of the dates lies within that interval.

Here it is a toy example with just three column dates.

```
DT <- data.table(d1=dmy(c("1-1-2019", "2-2-2019")), 
    d2=dmy(c("1-3-2019", "2-2-2022")), 
    d3=dmy(c("1-1-2020", "2-2-2021")),
    initial=dmy(c("1-1-2020","5-5-2022")), 
    final=dmy(c("1-3-2020","1-1-2023")))

         d1         d2         d3    initial      final
 2019-01-01 2019-03-01 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-03-01
 2019-02-02 2022-02-02 2021-02-02 2022-05-05 2023-01-01
```

I can do it like this: (it can also be used to filter instead of creating a new column)

```
DT[,new:=(d1 >= initial & d1 <= final) | (d2 >= initial & d2 <= final) | 
   (d3 >= initial & d3 <= final)]
```

But this is quite long, specially if I had more than three columns.

I have tried this compact version

```
DT[,any( c(d1,d2,d3 ) %within% interval(initial, final))]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

What is the simplest way I can do it?
Any solution with other packages are also welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative:

```r
DT[, new := rowSums(sapply(.SD, between, initial, final)) > 0,
   .SDcols = c("d1", "d2", "d3")]
DT
#            d1         d2         d3    initial      final    new
#        <Date>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date>     <Date> <lgcl>
# 1: 2019-01-01 2019-03-01 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-03-01   TRUE
# 2: 2019-02-02 2022-02-02 2021-02-02 2022-05-05 2023-01-01  FALSE
```

Make sure you're using `data.table::between` ... if you have a conflict between that and `dplyr::between`, the latter will complain (since it requires that its lower/upper bounds are length-1).

This answer is both vectorized and as efficient as one can be with an arbitrary number of columns. That is, it will call `between` once per *column* (vectorized), and `rowSums` only once regardless of the number of columns. (Also, `rowSums(.)` is generally faster than `apply(., 1, any)` or similar canonical R methods.)

Comment: OK, I have choosen your solution because it's much faster. And bevause he already has a lot of points :)
I still need to decide how to deal with missings here.

Comment: I wasn't point-groveling (he's doing _very well_, but I'm not hurting ;-), but missingness is an important issue. In which variables do you have `NA` values?

Comment: That's the point, if any of d1,d2 or d3 is NA I would just ignore them and go on with the other.
But if any of the interval defining dates is NA then it has to be carefully decided.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like you must first come up with the "spoken logic" of what you want done with that. What does it mean, *intuitively*, when one end of the date-range is undefined? Should you assume `-Inf` or `Inf`, or would it be more reasonable to assume `Sys.Date()`? Or do you think you want to impute based on other observations? Lots of good questions ... and I think it's really too context-sensitive for me to glibly make recommendations. Good luck :-)

Comment: @r2evans I revoted after reading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not vectorized.  So, we can use a group by with sequence of rows

```
DT[, new := any( c(d1,d2,d3 ) %within% interval(initial, final)),
      by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

-output

```
DT
#           d1         d2         d3    initial      final   new
#1: 2019-01-01 2019-03-01 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-03-01  TRUE
#2: 2019-02-02 2022-02-02 2021-02-02 2022-05-05 2023-01-01 FALSE
```

---

Or a Vectorized function

```
DT[, new := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x >= initial & 
    x <= final)),.SDcols = patterns('^d\\d+$')]
DT
#          d1         d2         d3    initial      final   new
#1: 2019-01-01 2019-03-01 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-03-01  TRUE
#2: 2019-02-02 2022-02-02 2021-02-02 2022-05-05 2023-01-01 FALSE
```

Comment: What is not vectorized "any" or %within%?

Comment: Your solution is more original, but I have chosen r2evans's because it's much faster and I think it's easier to deal with missings with the na.rm option.

Comment: @skan Can you please remove your comments